# Help debugging implementation of Draper QFT adder

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, quantum-fourier-transform

I am attempting to implement the adder found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0205095.pdf).

[image: fourier adder circuit]

Here is the code:

```
#build the phi adder circuit
#controlled phase gates are .cp() def phi_add(num_bits):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(2*num_bits,num_bits)
    #initialize a register
    #qc.x(0)
    qc.x(1)
    #qc.x(2)
    #qc.x(3)
    #initialize b register
    qc.x(4)
    qc.x(5)
    qc.x(6)
    qc.x(7)
    #append Fourier transform to second register
    qc.append(QFT(num_qubits=4),range(num_bits,2*num_bits))
    #append phase addition gates
    for k in range(num_bits):
        for j in range(num_bits-k):
            qc.cp(2*np.pi/2**(j+1),control_qubit=num_bits-k-1-j,target_qubit=2*num_bits-k-1)
    #append inverse Fourier transform to second register
    qc.append(QFT(num_qubits=4,inverse=True),range(num_bits,2*num_bits))
    qc.measure(range(num_bits,2*num_bits), range(num_bits))
    return qc
```

Resulting in this diagram:

[image: Fourier adder circuit diagram]

Which yields results that don't look very good:

[image: Aer simulation results]

**EDIT:** I found qiskit.circuit.library.DraperQFTAdder, which implements it but I still can't see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is how you are using [`QFT`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.QFT.html). `do_swaps` should be false. And sice its default value is true, you will need to pass it explicitly:

```
QFT(num_qubits=4, do_swaps=False)
```

and

```
QFT(num_qubits=4, do_swaps=False, inverse=True)
```

Note also that, since the two registers have same size and the second register contains all 1s, the output will always be the value in the first register minus one.

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of the option but didn't understand why it'd need to be off. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a bit of code experimentation, the order in which you target qubits depending on `k` is wrong: if you target the lines in the circuit from top to bottom as `k` increases, you'll get the circuit as it is presented in the paper, and the answer on the basis states will be a basis state as well. (You can do that by changing your code to use `target_qubit=num_bits+k`.)

Comment: I think this is notational. For me, 3↔7 ... 0↔4 and 0↔0 ... 3↔3.